# Is there any performance difference between compare method and compare class?

Tags: c#, sorting, generic-collections

Are there any difference in performance between

```
List<T>.Sort Method (Comparison<T>)
```

and

```
List<T>.Sort Method (IComparer<T>)?
```

Does exists any structural (software architectural) benefits?

When do you use the compare method instead of compare class and vice versa?

EDIT:

The `List<T>.Sort Method (IComparer<T>)` is faster. Thanks Jim Mischel!

The performance difference is around 1% on my PC.

It seems that the compare class is the faster one.

Comment: Did you tried yourself first? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Conceivably, the `IComparer<T>` method requires the instantiation of an object that implements `IComparer<T>`--which would involve time and memory.  If you wanted to share comparison across multiple classes, `IComparer<T>` would be the more flexible route.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: Yes I can check the performance in both case my self, but the performance is not the most important question in this situation despite of you could think at first look. How to use it is more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I recall, `List.Sort(Comparer<T>)` instantiates an `IComparer<T>` and then calls `List.Sort(IComparer<T>)`.

It looks something like this:

```
class SortComparer<T>: IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Comparison<T> _compare;
    public SortComparer(Comparison<T> comp)
    {
        _compare = comp;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return _compare(x, y);
    }
}

public Sort(Comparison<T> comp)
{
    Sort(new SortComparer(comp));
}
```

So they really end up doing the same thing. When I timed this stuff (back in .NET 3.5), `Sort(IComparer<T>)` was slightly faster because it didn't have to do the extra dereference on every call. But the difference really wasn't big enough to worry about. This is definitely a case of use whatever works best in your code rather than what performs the fastest.

A little more about it, including information about default `IComparer` implementations: [Of Comparison and IComparer](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=781)

Comment: I didn't know that, nice knowledge of the inner implementation :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the first accepts a method (anonymous or not) and the second accepts an instance of a comparer object. Sometimes it is easier to define complex and customizeable comparer classes rather than write everything inside a single function.

I prefer the first for simple sorting in one dimension and the latter for multidimensional sorting in e.g. data grids.

Using a comparer you can have private members which can often help with caching. This is useful in certain scenarios (again, in complex sorting of a large data set displayed in a grid).

Comment: This kind of answer is what I expect. Thanks!